# Magnetic Circuits: Why is magnetic Flux constant through one loop of a magnetic Circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

Wikipedia states that for a [magnetic circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit), the magnetic flux throughout the path of the circuit is constant. If I understand right, this means that 
\begin{align}
\Phi_1 = \Phi_2 = \Phi_3 = \Phi_4 = \Phi_5
\end{align}

[image]

Wikipedia claims that this is due to Gauss's law for magnetic fields, that is, the magnetic field is divergence-free. I could understand to be a valid argument if the magnetic field was actually confined to the region of the ferromagnetic material, but it is not.

Am I assuming right that there is a magnetic field outside the region of the iron of the magnetic circuit, that is simply not taken into account?

If so, why is this outer magnetic field neglected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article:

> The current in typical electric circuits is confined to the circuit, with very little "leakage". In typical magnetic circuits not all of the magnetic field is confined to the magnetic circuit because magnetic permeability also exists outside materials (see vacuum permeability). Thus, there may be significant "leakage flux" in the space outside the magnetic cores, which must be taken into account but is often difficult to calculate.

So you are right, the field is not all confined in the "circuit". However, if we are using materials, fields, etc. such that most of the field is confined inside the material, the idea of magnetic circuits can still useful. This is true of pretty much any model.